# The uninvited chinese charactres code on mode line

Tags: emacs

After I install latest doom.emacs from scratch,

some messy codes appeared on the mode line

[image]
[image]

How could disappear them?

Comment: Bisect your init file to find the culprit. Or if you can repro the problem by starting Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file), then consider filing a bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by missing install of [all-the-icons](https://github.com/domtronn/all-the-icons.el). As per the advice [here](https://github.com/seagle0128/doom-modeline/issues/310#issuecomment-595069742), run `M-x all-the-icons-install-fonts`.